# Button Click not working as with link

Tags: html

I am having a button with link but it keep opening in the same browser with wrong url i.e. https://localhost:44374/www.google.com.au

```
 <button class="IPbutton" id="" type="button" onclick="location.href='www.google.com.au';"> www.google.com.au </button>
```

Comment: Add `https://` before url in `location.href`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the link is fully qualified with protocol etc:

```
<button class="IPbutton" id="" type="button" onclick="location.href='https://www.google.com.au';"> www.google.com.au </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

Using `window.location.href`

```
<button class="IPbutton" id="" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.google.com.au';"> www.google.com.au </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `<button class="IPbutton" id="" type="button" onclick="location.href='https://www.google.com.au/';"> www.google.com.au </button>`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this 
`<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html" target="_blank"><button class="IPbutton" id="" type="button" > button1</button> </a>`
but if u want with onclick 
`<button class="IPbutton" id="" type="button" onclick="window.location='www.google.com.au'"> button2 </button>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change `location.href` to `window.location`